# Запуск python скрипта со страницы на django

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

Есть определенная кнопка в ***list.html***:

```
{% load static %}
...
{% include "execute.html" %}
...
<button type="button" id="id">Execute Script</button>
```

***views.py:***

```
import subprocess
import os
...
def exec_com(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        command = request.POST['cmd']
        os.chdir('../static/tools/')
        return subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
```

***urls.py:***

```
url(r'^execute/$', views.exec_com, name='execute'),
```

***execute.html:***

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.cookie.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready', function(){
   $('#id').on('click', function(){
        data = {
            "cmd": "id.py"
        }
        $.ajax({
             headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
             url : window.location.href,
             type: "POST",
             data: data,
             dataType: "text",
             async: "asynchronous",
             success: function(data) {
                  alert("Executed.")
                  console.log(data)
             },
             error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                  alert("Something wrong.")
                  console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText)
             }
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
```

При нажатии выполнения скрипта не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я пропустил или не так сделал?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно написать функцию на `python`, которая будет ожидать запрос с какими-то параметрами или без них по указаному адресу (url) и обращаться к ней. Статика тут не причем, она обрабатывается браузером, python-скрипт обрабатывается интерпретаторм.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^url_name/$', views.get_for_url_name)
```

Функция, которая обработает запрос

views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_for_url_name(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = ' method GET'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = ' method POST'
    else:
        data = ''
    a = {'Hello world': data}
    response = JsonResponse(data)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

Теперь можно обратиться к этой функции из браузера `http://localhost:port/get_for_url_name` или написать соответствующий запрос на `JS`

Должно работать :)

Comment: Могу ли я попросить у Вас пример подобной реализации?

Comment: @SilencedOne05 отредактировал ответ

Comment: @igor-sergeevich отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @SilencedOne05 Подебажте, посмотрите что работает, что не работает

Comment: @igor-sergeevich Работает запрос. Есть вероятность, что os.chdir пытается переключиться на несуществующую папку, или сам "отлов" запроса работает некорректно. Но я не знаю, как проверить, в какой папке работает views.py изначально, чтобы осуществить корректный переход. Но "отлов" данных запроса выглядит корректно... Попробую просто импортировать скрипт и запустить его так.

Comment: @SilencedOne05 укажите полный путь

Comment: @igor-sergeevich Да, поймал:
`500: FileNotFoundError at /execute/
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../static/tools'`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58435/discussion-between-silencedone05-and-igor-sergeevich).